# Are all toilet bolts installed from under the floor?

Tags: floor, toilet, bolts, plumbing-fixture

My mom has an older toilet. When is became loose, in order to tighten the bolts she had to hire someone to go under the house.

We just got a new toilet. I was hoping to install it as a d.i.y project. In this case, will someone need to go under the house in order to install the new floor bolts that came with the purchased toilet? Or should we be able to place them from inside and tighten them?

Answer (score 7):

A typical toilet has a flange that's bolted to the floor and stays there.

Bolts are then turn upside down, with the head down, and the toilet sits on these. The threaded end faces up and the nut goes onto it.

So, a typical toilet install is closet bolts that have threads facing up. No need to go under the floor, be it a 3rd floor bathroom, a 1st floor bathroom or a basement bathroom.

Comment: Not that some flanges are glued when there is no underneath.